# How to make Token Authentication more secure

Tags: asp.net, api, authentication, oauth, access-token

I have implemented token based authentication in my web application based on an [article](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1090252/token-based-authentication-using-postman-as-client).

Man in the middle token theft is possible in this implementation. So, i have added IP address check in the token and it works fine in the LAN and WiFi.

But, when comes to the mobile network the IP address has changed when the user moves and the user needs to enter the credentials again.

Can anyone please suggest how to make the token Authorization more secure?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use transport security?

Comment: @stuartd It depends upon my customer, some customers use SSL and some may not. So, you can consider it as Non-SSL.

Answer (score 0):

OpenID Connect should be used for Secure Authentication. (ie NOT OAuth)

The [OpenID Connect MODRNA Authentication Profile 1.0](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-modrna-authentication-1_0-06.html)

Would be the Current Best Practice for Mobile Devices.